# Can you attach a handler function with arguments to an onclick event for a number of elements in a loop?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am trying to set an `onclick` event for thumbnails that are dynamically populated from a database. I need to set the function to handle an argument, which is the id of the bigger picture the thumbnail represents. The code I have now sets all the thumbnails to point to #18. If you see in the for-loop, it is supposed to die at 17:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    document.getElementById('tat' + i).onclick = function() { display(i); }; 
}
```

(My thumbnail `<img />`s all have `id="tat0"`, `id="tat1"`, `id="tat2"`, `id="tat3"` etc.)
(`display()` loads the larger pic that the thumbnail represents into a separate element)

Each thumbnail gets this `onclick` function, so I know the for loop is accessing each one by its ID properly (stepping through for each `i`) so why are all the `display(i)` being assigned to 18? Can you assign an `onclick` function to handle parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

Comment: Bottom line of the problem: Each event handler references the same `i`. After the loop finished, `i` has the value `18`. The solution is to generate event handlers which do not share the same variable. This is neither related to `getElementById` nor `onclick`.

Comment: You are right, I had to pull back and come at it a different way:

function initOnClick(){
 var images = document.getElementById("thumbs").getElementsByTagName("img");
 
 for (var t=0; t < images.length; t++){
  images[t].onclick = function() { 
   var id = this.id.substr(3);
   display(id);
  }
 }   
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a closure function to generate your handlers.

```
function genHandler( param ) {
  return function() {
     // use all params in here
     display( param );
  }
}
```

and then assign your events similarly

```
for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
  document.getElementById('tat' + i).onclick = genHandler( i );
}
```

Comment: "You need a closure function to generate your handlers". The OPs event handler is a closure as well. In your code, `genHandler` is actually not a closure.

Answer (score 0):

It might also work, if you just add 'i' as a parameter to your function.

Comment: Which function? You mean `function(i) { display(i); };`? That won't work. The first argument passed to an event handler is the event object, if any (IE).

Comment: You are right... A hack: `function() { display(this.id.substr(3)); };` could be used, if the ids are of type 'tat0', like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your onclick handler in a function will create a closure that carrys the current scope with it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    document.getElementById('tat' + i).onclick = (function(a) {
        return (function() {
            display(a);
        });
    })(i);
}​
```